# How to pass an camera image to another activity?

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I saw a video of how to put an camera access on android studio but I didn´t have much space in my current activity so I made an clicklistener on the image and when the user clicks on image, it goes to another activity where the image appears bigger, but when I click on the image it goes to the other acivity but doesn´t show the image. I saw other questions but or they ask about how to pass an image that is on drawable resources or the answer doesn´t fit me.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fazer_perguntas);
        photoCamera = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.photoCamera);

        photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        photo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
        photo3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo3);

        photoCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera,0);
            }
        });

        photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BigPhoto.class);
                p.putExtra("idphoto",photo.getId());
                p.putExtra("idphoto2",photo2.getId());
                p.putExtra("idphoto3",photo3.getId());
                startActivity(p);
            }
        });
        {
         @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Intent selfiSrc = new Intent(this, BigPhoto.class);
        selfiSrc.putExtra("data",bitmap);
        startActivity(selfiSrc); 
        }

    }
}
```

This is part of my firstactivity java class. photo2 and photo3 are other imageviews that I will do the same thing for photo.

```
package com.example.ritalopes.help;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BigPhoto extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView photo, photo2, photo3, bigphoto;
    private Uri path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_photo);

        photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        photo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
        photo3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo3);
        bigphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bigphoto);

        Intent pho = getIntent();
        int image1 = pho.getIntExtra("idphoto",0);
        int image2 = pho.getIntExtra("idphoto2",0);
        int image3 = pho.getIntExtra("idphoto3",0);

        Intent take = getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) take.getParcelableExtra("data");

       bigphoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }}
```

This is my secondactivity javaclass where I want to pass the image(s) to. I tried that code envolving a Uri but didn´t worked out.
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Do you want to take photo on click of the image or you want to take on activity result because you are firing intent onActivityResult also..?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very clear...

First, you have to add an OnClickListener for all images, not only for `photo`
Then, you have to pass extra data to Intent, like you've done. But, don't pass the ID of the imageView but the drawable ID you want to show in fullscreen.

Do you want to display images for drawable ? Or Bitmaps ? If bitmap, I think `intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)` will work as Bitmap is Parcelable.

Comment: I don´t really know the difference between displaying images for drawable or bitmaps, I just want to display the cameraimage on another activity.

Comment: I tried your code but the image just shows on the other activity when I took the photo and when I click on the photo again, the image disappears.

Comment: I need to put the intent inside the clicklistener, but when I do that it it doesn´t recognize the bitmap symbol can you help me please?.Thanks for your first answer by the way

Comment: Do it step by step: first, retrieve an image from the camera and then, pass it to the other activity. Do you have yet retrieved the image from camera ?

Comment: I´ve edited my code . You can see it by yourself now.

Comment: Many questions remaining... What are `photo2` and `photo3` in your MainActivity ? Do you need them ? Why do you start the "BigPhoto" after receiving the image from the camera ? You just have to store it in class member and pass it to the Big Activity when user taps on `photo` right ?

Answer (score 0):

if your purpose is sending an image in order to preview image in the another activity. I recommend you try to use this library. just add it in your gradle file in your project.

https://github.com/chathuralakmal/AndroidImagePopup

this preview image library have using Picasso Library to you can show your preview is so easy. and it also contain close button for you.

it help me , i hope this would save you time.